# How to know whether a RecyclerView / LinearLayoutManager is scrolled to top or bottom?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently I am using the follow code to check whether SwipeRefreshLayout should be enabled.

```
private void laySwipeToggle() {
    if (mRecyclerView.getChildCount() == 0 || mRecyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0) {
        mLaySwipe.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mLaySwipe.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

But here is the problem. When it's scrolled to another item's view's boundary `mRecyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop()` also returns 0.

[image: The problem]

Is there something like `RecyclerView.isScrolledToBottom()` or `RecyclerView.isScrolledToTop()`?

EDIT: `(mRecyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0 && linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0)` kind of does the `RecyclerView.isScrolledToTop()`, but what about `RecyclerView.isScrolledToBottom()`?

Comment: I suppose the latter can be achieved by verifying the bottom of the recyclerview against the last child i.e something on the lines of

mRecyclerView.getBottom()== linearLayoutmanager.findViewbyPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1).getBottom()

Comment: @Saren Arterius you might want to take a  look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33515549/1118886)

Answer (score 119):

The solution is in the layout manager.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

// Add this to your Recycler view
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

// To check if at the top of recycler view
if(layoutManager.firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==0){
    // Its at top
}

// To check if at the bottom of recycler view
if(layoutManager.lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==data.size()-1){
    // Its at bottom
}
```

**EDIT**

In case your item size is larger than the screen use the following to detect the top event.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

int pos = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

if(linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(pos).getTop()==0 && pos==0){
    return true;
}
```

**PS: Actually, if you place the `RecyclerView` directly inside the `SwipeRefreshview` you wouldn't need to do this**

Comment: No, it still happens when the RecyclerView is the direct child of SwipeRefreshLayout. But checking the firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition fixes the problem. I need to point something here. If none of the items are fully visible firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() returns -1. So this solution will not work if the first item doesn't fit into the RecyclerView when it is scrolled to top. But it is a very rare situation.

Comment: @eluleci : Check for whether list is on top

RecyclerView rc=(RecyclerView)view;
            LinearLayoutManager lm= (LinearLayoutManager) rc.getLayoutManager();
            if(lm.findViewByPosition(lm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()).getTop()==0 && lm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()==0)
                return true; //This would work evn if the item is of a larger size than screen

Comment: Great! My rows are short enough but I think it'll will be helpful to others. Thanks

Comment: This would fail if the item (first or last) is larger than the entire screen. Because, `first/lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` will return -1, implies, there is no fully visible item at all.

Comment: @SubinSebastian : I so wish people would take time to read the complete answer. Th edit on Jun 1 mentions the very case

Comment: Only `lastVisibleItemPosition` worked with me without `Completely`

Comment: Both `lastVisibleItemPosition` and `lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` don't work. (cannot resolve method). 

Help?

Comment: Hello, I solved my problem - use `final android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327013/android-cannot-resolve-method-findfirstvisibleitemposition)

Comment: Also, use `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition`.

Comment: `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` will FAIL if the last item's height is greater than the screen height. It means that the last item is visible, but not completely visible, so `layout.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()=-1(RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)`. Use `lastVisibleItemPosition` and check for the bottom of the last view in layout will be safer.

Comment: recyclerView.getLayoutManager() doesn't have those methods, because it returns a LayoutManager and not a LinearLayoutManager(which has the method you want)

Comment: @DragosRachieru What am I missing here, Isn't that what's explained in the solution via code?

Comment: i was explaining to @Stardust why there's no such method

Answer (score 91):

You can try `recyclerView.canScrollVertically(int direction)`, if you just need to know whether it possible to scroll or not.

Direction integers:

- -1 for up
- 1 for down
- 0 will always return false.

Comment: This would have to be repeated on an interval though, right?

Comment: You can out this in recyclerView.addOnScrollListener..it works like a charm...thanks

Comment: Great! This returns a false when we reach the end of scrolling, I needed this event.

Comment: Excellent. Use this in `onScrollStateChanged` works for me.

Comment: just remember: on case no item to display or item not enough to scroll, it will always return false

Comment: `recyclerView.canScrollVertically(RecyclerView.FOCUS_DOWN) == false` you have reached to bottom

Comment: direction integers: -1 for up, 1 for down, 0 will always return false.

Answer (score 33):

In order to check whether `RecyclerView` is scrolled to bottom. Use the following code.

```
/**
     * Check whether the last item in RecyclerView is being displayed or not
     *
     * @param recyclerView which you would like to check
     * @return true if last position was Visible and false Otherwise
     */
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Some Additional info**

If you want to implement `ScrollToBottom` in `RecyclerView` when `Edittext` is `tapped` then i recommend you add **1 second delay** like this:

```
 edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
// The scrolling can happen instantly before keyboard even opens up so to handle that we add 1 second delay to scrolling
                        recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);

                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Worked for me. I had to add it to the RecyclerView's **addOnScrollListener()** though

Comment: this doesnt work for the trivial case where there is one item in the recyclerview and it is fully visible.

Answer (score 25):

@Saren Arterius, Using the **addOnScrollListener** of **RecycleView**, you can find the scrolling top or bottom of Vertical RecycleView like below,

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);

rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                if (dy < 0) {
                    // Recycle view scrolling up...

                } else if (dy > 0) {
                    // Recycle view scrolling down...
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

You can detect top by using the following

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
          }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(isRecyclerViewAtTop())
            {
                //your recycler view reached Top do some thing
             }
        }
    });

  private boolean isRecyclerViewAtTop()   {
        if(recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0)
            return true;
        return recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
    }
```

This will detect top when you release the finger once reached top,
if you want to detect as soon the reacyclerview reaches top check `if(isRecyclerViewAtTop())` inside `onScrolled`  method

Comment: This seems to be wrong. `getChildAt()` returns the first child of the `ViewGroup`, which could (and will) be different from the first element of the list. If that child happens to be perfectly aligned with the top of the recyclerview, your `IsRecyclerViewAtTop()` method will return true, even though it is not at the top.

Answer (score 6):

Use **recyclerView.canScrollVertically(int direction)** to check if top or bottom of the scroll reached.

**direction = 1 for scroll down (bottom)**

**direction = -1 for scroll up (top)**

if method return false that means you reached either top or bottom depends on the direction.

Answer (score 5):

Just keep a reference to your layoutManager and set onScrollListener on your recycler view like this

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItemIndex = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        //synchronizew loading state when item count changes
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading)
            if ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= firstVisibleItemIndex) {
                // Loading NOT in progress and end of list has been reached
                // also triggered if not enough items to fill the screen
                // if you start loading
                loading = true;
            } else if (firstVisibleItemIndex == 0){
                // top of list reached
                // if you start loading
                loading = true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `setOnScrollListner` is deprecated now.

Comment: You should use `addOnScrollListener` because as @shajeelAfzal said `setOnScrollListener` is deprecated now , you should use `addOnScrollListener` because as @shajeelAfzal said `setOnScrollListener` is deprecated now , check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setOnScrollListener%28android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener%29])

Comment: What is `previousTotal`?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this it's work for me

```
      mRecycleView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int topRowVerticalPosition = (recyclerView == null || recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) ?
                        0 : recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager1 = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                int firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager1.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(firstVisibleItem == 0 && topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I have written a RecyclerViewHelper to know the recyclerview is at top or at bottom.

```
public class RecyclerViewHelper {
public static boolean isAtTop(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return isAtTopBeforeIceCream(recyclerView);
    } else {
        return !ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(recyclerView, -1);
    }
}

private static boolean isAtTopBeforeIceCream(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    if (layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
        int pos = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(pos).getTop() == recyclerView.getPaddingTop() && pos == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public static boolean isAtBottom(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return isAtBottomBeforeIceCream(recyclerView);
    } else {
        return !ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(recyclerView, 1);
    }
}

private static boolean isAtBottomBeforeIceCream(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    int count = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
    if (layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
        int pos = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        int lastChildBottom = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(pos).getBottom();
        if (lastChildBottom == recyclerView.getHeight() - recyclerView.getPaddingBottom() && pos == count - 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

To find out if the RecyclerView is scrolled to bottom, you could reuse the methods used for the scrollbar.

This is the calculation, for convenience written as a Kotlin extension function:

```
fun RecyclerView.isScrolledToBottom(): Boolean {
    val contentHeight = height - (paddingTop + paddingBottom)
    return computeVerticalScrollRange() == computeVerticalScrollOffset() + contentHeight
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! 
I saw some issues where the scroll size was only 1 off, even though I was scrolled at the bottom (probably some rounding issues)
So I changed the code to use a margin:
`fun RecyclerView.isScrolledToBottom(margin: Int = 1): Boolean {
        val contentHeight = height - (paddingTop + paddingBottom)
        return computeVerticalScrollRange() - computeVerticalScrollOffset() - contentHeight >= margin
    }`

Comment: I mean, smaller or equal to margin. Like this:
`fun RecyclerView.isScrolledToBottom(margin: Int = 1): Boolean {
        val contentHeight = height - (paddingTop + paddingBottom)
        return computeVerticalScrollRange() - computeVerticalScrollOffset() - contentHeight <= margin
    }`

Answer (score 2):

If you're still looking for an answer in 2022, here you go:

```
 mRecyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener((view, i, i1, i2, i3) -> {
            if(!mRecyclerView.canScrollVertically(RecyclerView.FOCUS_DOWN)){
                 // reached the bottom of the list, load more data
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with the OnTouchListener:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            || e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        if (mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() > 0)
        {
        // beginning of the recycler 
        }

        if (mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()+1 < recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount())
        {
        // end of the recycler 
        }         
     }             
return false;
}
```