# Android: Cannot resolve method 'findFirstVisibleItemPosition()'?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to write a code for endless scroll on a recycler view. This is the snippet that gives me a compiler error:

```
@Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if ( (visibleItemCount+pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                }
```

And the declaration I've written before is:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

And mLayoutManager is an object of class RecyclerView.LayoutManager

Comment: Codes look ok, maybe show your other related codes, or logcat for error

Comment: This is the exact error I'm getting: 
`Error:(62, 51) error: cannot find symbol method findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`

Comment: Check your import, make sure you are using `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`mLayoutManager is an object of class RecyclerView.LayoutManager` is wrong, you should use `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager` for `mLayoutManager`, so:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this); 
//above 'LinearLayoutManager' is from
//'android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager'

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

then `mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();` call should be ok in `onScrolled(...);`.

Hope this help!

Comment: I have imported that but my object's class might need to be changed. I'll try your variation and see how that works. Thank you

Comment: I've added both these lines to my import code, still shows a red line.

`import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;`

Comment: Alright mLayoutManager was supposed to be an object of LinearLayoutManager ... even though I had imported it the compiler converted it to RecyclerView.LayoutManager.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What About `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`??

Comment: It is one of `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`, check [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)