# Android studio not recognizing a method?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use the method  `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` from a `LinearLayoutManager`. The apis show that this method exists, but it is not recognized nor shown in autocompletion.

Other methods from this layout work (some at least), and `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager` is imported.

What could be wrong?

edit: here´s my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.skate.socialskate"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.2'

}
```

Comment: Show us your build.gradle file.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327013/android-cannot-resolve-method-findfirstvisibleitemposition

Comment: Looks like this is only under v7

Comment: @Eugene there it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an [appcompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```