# Android: Cannot resolve symbol "setLayoutManager"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

trying use racycler view, but cannot set layout manager

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

writes Cannot resolve symbol "setLayoutManager" and Unknown Class on llm

```
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

already have

Comment: Take a look at this and check our imports.  you should use android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager for llm

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327013/android-cannot-resolve-method-findfirstvisibleitemposition

Comment: import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView; imported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the code above place in the onCreate method? otherwise, you may consider adding the name of the activity or class.