# Recyclerview indicates that reaches the last item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `recycleView` that I need to observe when the last item is reached but I have notice the it always indicate that I reached the last item even if I haven't scrolled yet.
My code for setting up the recycler:

```
newsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
newsRecyclerView.setFocusable(false);
newsRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getContext(), newsDetails, categoryNumber);
newsRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
```

My xml code is:

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/news_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/news_top_stories_title_text_view" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when RecyclerView reaches the bottom most position while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127734/detect-when-recyclerview-reaches-the-bottom-most-position-while-scrolling)

Comment: you need to use `onScrollListener` on recyclerview and then find out last `((LinearLayoutManager) vYourRecycler.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Khemraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6891563/khemraj) who give the tip for solution
because I have a `recyclerview` inside `NestedScrollView` and `coordinator layout` as parent for them

I have solved my problem like this:

```
public Disposable observeNestedScroll(LoadMoreListener listener) {
    return RxNestedScrollView.scrollChangeEvents(nestedScrollView)
            .subscribe(
                    viewScrollChangeEvent -> {
                        NestedScrollView nestedScrollView =(NestedScrollView) viewScrollChangeEvent.view();
                        if(nestedScrollView.getChildAt(nestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
                            if ((viewScrollChangeEvent.scrollY() >= (nestedScrollView.getChildAt(nestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - nestedScrollView.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
                                    viewScrollChangeEvent.scrollY() > viewScrollChangeEvent.oldScrollY()) {
                                listener.onLoadMore();
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my code that I put in my Util, and use anywhere.

```
Util.setRecyclerViewLastPositionListner(rv, linearLayoutManager , new UtilitiesV2.OnLastPositionReached() {
            @Override
            public void onReached() {
                // last position reached
            }
        });
```

Put this in Util.

```
 private boolean userScrolled = true;
    int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;


    public interface OnLastPositionReached {
        void onReached();
    }

    public void setRecyclerViewLastPositionListner(RecyclerView rvBooksMockTest, final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager, final OnLastPositionReached onLastPositionReached) {
        rvBooksMockTest.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    userScrolled = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                // Here get the child count, item count and visibleitems
                // from layout manager

                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                // Now check if userScrolled is true and also check if
                // the item is end then update recycler view and set
                // userScrolled to false
                if (userScrolled && (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) == totalItemCount) {
                    userScrolled = false;
                    if (onLastPositionReached != null) onLastPositionReached.onReached();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Update** 
According to your requirement, here is NestedScrollView bottom reach listener.

```
nestedScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        if (nestedScrollView != null) {
            if (nestedScrollView.getChildAt(0).getBottom() <= (nestedScrollView.getHeight() + nestedScrollView.getScrollY())) {
                //scroll view is at bottom
            } else {
                //scroll view is not at bottom
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it gets called once  when the view created

Comment: May be your RecyclerView is not scrollable. Or it has 1-2 items.

Comment: I have a `scrollview` which contains a` constraintlayout` that contains the `recyclerview` so I should consider to observe the scrollview instead?

Comment: Try with NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView.

Comment: Can you provide me with a link to detect when the `nestedScrollView` reaches the end

Comment: What is your purpose? to load more items?

Comment: Yes for load more items using retrofit and rxjava

Answer (score 0):

I've seen to many responses for this question and I stand that all of them don't give accurate behavior as an outcome. However if you follow this approach I'm positive you'll get the best behavior.

**rvCategories** is your RecyclerView

**categoriesList** is the list passed to your adapter

```
binding.rvCategories.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
      override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                val position = (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                if (position + 1 == categoriesList.size) {
                   // END OF RECYCLERVIEW IS REACHED
                } else {
                    // END OF RECYCLERVIEW IS NOT REACHED
                }
        }
    })
```