# Is there a listener for the animated "bumpers" that appear at the end of the scrolls?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

When no more scrolling is possible in certain Android scrollable views, such as in `RecyclerViews`, a wavy grey animation is often fired to tell the user they have reached the end.

I don't know what this animation is called (which has made it hard for me to find information about it) so I'm calling it a "bumper". I have a picture of it below.

Anyway I want to trigger a process the moment the bumper has finished animating. Is there a listener I can attach to the bumper to achieve this?

It needs to be a listener I can correlate to a scroll, so hopefully the `onBumperStateChanged` listener (or whatever it's called) fires for the first time *before* the scroll listener's `onScrollStateChanged` fires its `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`.

(I have come to think that the bumper animation finishes *after* `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` is called, and may be responsible for jank I am seeing when I trigger my process immediately after `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`.)

Thanks!

John

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the reference it is called the `Overscroll Animation` and what you should do is to listen for RecyclerView's scroll ending not for the animation itself. Here is how you would do it.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Last", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
});
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342525/370073).

Comment: My concern is that the Overscroll Animation (thanks!) finishes *after* `onScrollStateChanged` is called, which is what's causing my problems. Are you sure the animation is finished *before*  `onScrollStateChanged` is called?

Comment: The animation is called at the same time as `onScrollStateChanged`. What exactly is your process that's causing the jank? Perhaps you're running some heavy operation on the UI thread which you shouldn't do.

Comment: I redraw a bitmap in the UI thread. It can't be redrawn on another thread. So I get jankiness during the Overscroll animation. Which is why I want the animation to end first. There is an onOverScrolled listener that maybe fires *before* `onScrollStateChanged`, which I could try . . .

Comment: I highly doubt that redrawing some bitmap is causing the jankiness. I suggest you double check your code to see if you're doing any heavy processing on the UI thread. It might be worth mentioning [Render Thread](https://medium.com/@workingkills/understanding-the-renderthread-4dc17bcaf979) is some new concept for separating animations from other UI drawing.