# How to detect if user has reached end of recyclerview in KOTLIN?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm using an API which returns JSON as a response. The JSON has a boolean key "can_load" which holds true if there are items to be displayed. In this API there's a query parameter as the pagenum. At first I hardcode the page number to 1 so that the first set of items is displayed(20 items are displayed at first). I want to increment the page number by 1 when the user reaches the end of the recyclerview and there is more data to be displayed. How can I detect if the user has reached the end of recyclerview?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect when RecyclerView reaches the bottom most position while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127734/detect-when-recyclerview-reaches-the-bottom-most-position-while-scrolling)