# Change layout Manager programatically in recylerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, android-adapter

I want to change layoutmanager **stackFromEnd** and **reverseLayout** change when view is inflated. I have nested recylerview. So when recylerview inflated, i need to check that recylerview has more item than single screen i.e. I have more than items to scroll. I will show in image.

[image]

Also other condition when item is half cut from bottom edge.

[image].

On that basis I want to change layout on that. Is it possible to that and how?
I tried to some stack overflow [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127734/detect-when-recyclerview-reaches-the-bottom-most-position-while-scrolling) but it not's work. So anyone know how to achieve that thing?.

So I wonder if there is any listener that is called when the RecyclerView has finished laying down its items for the first time, making it possible to set the layout manager.

Comment: Sorry that, I may have a misunderstanding about the question, so, are you attempting to have a load more mechanism?

Comment: I want to only check that recyclerview has more item

Comment: @PutraNugraha I want to check that RV has more item, i.e. RV items are not fitting on first time when view is inflated.

Comment: I think can get window height and then substract with total of item height (assuming you have recycler view item with fixed layout_height). But probs, this is not the best practice

Comment: @PutraNugraha can you show me example how?

Comment: Sure, Im putting it as answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731094/10467286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming you have a parent view for your recycler views, e.g. `NestedScrollView`. Then you will need to get the height of your `NestedScrollView` after it being created in your screen

```
var nestedScrollViewHeight = 0
yourNestedScrollView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    yourNestedScrollView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    nestedScrollViewHeight = yourNestedScrollView.height
                }
            }
        )
```

And then you can check whether this `NestedScrollView` height surpass your screen height, you can get your screen height using `windowManager` in Activity

```
val screenHeight = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.bounds.height()
```

So, after obtaining both `screenHeight` and `nestedScrollViewHeight` you can then substract to check whether `nestedScrollViewHeight` is larger than `screenHeight`

Comment: thanks for example. Where need to put this code inside my activity or in my first adapter where I'm setting my second adapter?. Also if in my activity how can i acces my second adapter RV?

Comment: I think need you to update your question by put your code, that should make clear where to put this code