# How to check recycler view screen height for visible item programmatically in android

Tags: android

My case is i m having pagination concept for showing accounts say first time when i loaded i got accounts less than 5 so i have a check that accounts.size < = 5 then i only initiate next set of data without user action & scroll also wont be possible for accounts less than 5.

lets say i got acc size as 6 so 6 <= 5 so this condition fails & i cannot make api call also then scroll also wont be possible in higher screen sizes.

so in order to fix this issue for all screen resolutions (heights) i need to have condition if screen height exceeds this value have check for acc.size < = 7 then if screen height is between this value then have check for acc size < = 5.

Can any one let me know how to have above check for recycler screen height visible items ?

Please help

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127734/detect-when-recyclerview-reaches-the-bottom-most-position-while-scrolling

Comment: based on device height i need to identify & calculate?

Comment: for example i need to check if screen resolution is exceeding certain value then take limit as < = 5 else if exceeds certain value then take < =7