# Android RecyclerView inside RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` that displays different categories list. Each row item also contains `RecyclerView` to show category items' list. Parent `RecyclerView` is populated with vertial `LinearLayoutManager` and child `RecyclerViews` are populated with `GridLayoutManager` (2 columns). Child `RecyclerViews` are not showing all category items except first 2 even it has many category items. All remaining category items are hiding for specific category. In other words, you can say child `RecyclerView` is not expanding as much as items it contains.

I found different solution here but no one worked. That's why posting again.

Comment: You need to use only one recycler view. Provide more code of image with result and I will try to explain more

Comment: Even if you could have a nested recyclerview, you wouldn't be able to scroll it without some additional work.

Comment: You CAN have nested RecyclerViews (blew my mind when I heard this)...but this problem can't be solved without sharing code.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the top-level view to only support vertical scrolling and the children to _also_ only support vertical - is that right? A mockup or some sample code would really help here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67779647/6314955 check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve it with only one RecyclerView using this [library](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter). See the image below:

[image]

First create a Section class:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new MyHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data for each year
MySection section1 = new MySection("Categories 1", categories1DataList);
MySection section2 = new MySection("Categories 2", categories2DataList);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(section1);
sectionAdapter.addSection(section2);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        switch(sectionAdapter.getSectionItemViewType(position)) {
            case SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
                return 2;
            default:
                return 1;
        }
    }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Comment: I used this library and it worked great but little bit jerky. Now I want to add load more (want to load more records from server) functionality to this recyclerview list. How can I make it smooth and achieve pagination?

Comment: 1) create "addItem" method in your MySection class to add new items to your List; 2) Add items to your section using the "addItem" method; 3) call notifyDataSetChanged of sectionAdapter;

Comment: I didn't asked for this. I wanted to know how shall I know that my list has reached at bottom on scroll so that i can call an api for fetching next page records from server? I know that how to add new items in list. Could you please also help me to make it smooth because its little bit jerky.

Comment: for the "jerky" issue you should open another question and paste your code and your xml layouts, otherwise nobody can't help, for the load more you can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841740/how-to-know-whether-a-recyclerview-linearlayoutmanager-is-scrolled-to-top-or-b#

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, please consider marking my answer as correct then, clicking on the tick on the right top side of my answer. cheers