# Insert a RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, cardview

I am creating a set of 5 cards with the style of Google Now Cards. I am focusing first with the layout in general.

I'm using CardView and RecyclerView and what I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

This is my CardAdapter(Also the general adapter):

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.cardViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Card> item;
public CardAdapter(ArrayList<Card> item){
    this.item = item;
}

@Override
public cardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout,parent,false);
    cardViewHolder card = new cardViewHolder(v);
    return card;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(cardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.titel.setText(item.get(position).getTitel());
    holder.card_icon.setImageResource(item.get(position).getIcon());
    holder.load_more.setText("Load more");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return item.size();
}

public static class cardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView titel;
    ImageView card_icon;
    RecyclerView list_content;
    TextView load_more;
    public cardViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
         titel = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.titel);
        card_icon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_icon);
        load_more = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadmore);
        list_content = (RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
    }

}}
```

This is the MensaCardAdapter(the adapter for the first card, as far as I know everycard should have a particular adapter since they all have different layouts)

```
public class MensaCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MensaCardAdapter.MensaViewHolder> {
private List<MensaRow> items;

public MensaCardAdapter(List<MensaRow> items) {
    this.items = items;
}



@Override
public MensaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mensa_row,parent,false);
    return new MensaViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MensaViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.content.setText(items.get(position).getMensa_row_content());
    holder.img.setImageResource(items.get(position).getMensa_row_img());
    holder.title.setText(items.get(position).getTitel());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public class MensaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ImageView img;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView content;

    public MensaViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mensa_row_img);
        title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mensa_row_title);
        content = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mensa_row_content);
    }
}}
```

This is the CardLayout (for all the cards)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="110dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
android:padding="15dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp">


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Card Title"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card_icon"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/list_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/card_icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/card_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loadmore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load More"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titel"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titel"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the MensaCardLayout(layout for the first card)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:id="@+id/mensa_row_img"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:text="Angebot 1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/mensa_row_title"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mensa_row_img"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mensa_row_img"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mensa_row_img" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="Content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mensa_row_title"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mensa_row_title"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mensa_row_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/mensa_row_content" />
```

1- I can create the cards with no RecyclerView inside them without problems, but I have no idea how to write the activitymain class with 1 general RecyclerView and 5 independent and different RecyclerView.

The thing is that every card has different layout and different content, I am very new to android and I really don't understand any other complicated examples

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should not insert RecyclerView into another RecyclerView, this may cause many problems, and Google didn't recommend that. you should find another way.

Comment: What any other way do you recommend me?

Comment: I think you can put all the data into the outer RecyclerView, the header and footer can also be managed by the outer RecyclerView with different item type

Answer (score 0):

I investigated some of the same problems of rendering list inside an item of parent list. There's the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32086918/6094213) that helped me to solve this case.

Hope you'll be able to solve this case with it.

Answer (score 0):

> This implementation is **horizontal grid recycler view** inside a
> **vertical Liner recycler** view

**Activity**

```
class RecyclerGridActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var listAdapter: RecyclerCustomListAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_grid)

        val recyclerListView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerCustomList)

        listAdapter = RecyclerCustomListAdapter()
        recyclerListView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@RecyclerGridActivity)
        recyclerListView.adapter = listAdapter
        recyclerListView.addItemDecoration(TopSpacingItemDecoration(10))
        listAdapter.setContent(arrayOf(1,2,3,4), Example.shared.getData(), WeakReference(this))


    }
}
```

**It's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.recycler_grid_view.RecyclerGridActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerCustomList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**vertical Liner recycler Adapter**

```
class RecyclerCustomListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var items: Array<Int>

    private lateinit var data: List<User>

    private lateinit var gridAdapter: RecyclerGridAdapter

    private lateinit var ctx: WeakReference<Context>

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        gridAdapter = RecyclerGridAdapter()

        return ListViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_list_item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    fun setContent(items: Array<Int>, data: List<User>, ctx: WeakReference<Context>) {
        this.items = items
        this.data = data
        this.ctx = ctx
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    class ListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val recyclerGridView = itemView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerGrid)

        fun bind(data: List<User>, adapter: RecyclerGridAdapter, ctx: WeakReference<Context>) {

            recyclerGridView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager( ctx.get(), 1, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            recyclerGridView.adapter = adapter
            recyclerGridView.addItemDecoration(TopSpacingItemDecoration(10))
            adapter.setContent(data)
        }

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ListViewHolder-> {
                holder.bind(data, gridAdapter, ctx)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**It's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#4CAF50" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**horizontal grid recycler Adapter**

```
class RecyclerGridAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private lateinit var items: List<User>

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return GridViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_legacy_grid_item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is GridViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(items[position])
            }
        }
    }

    fun setContent(items: List<User>) {
        this.items = items
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    class GridViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val emailLabel = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.legacyGridEmail)

        fun bind(user: User) {
            emailLabel.text = user.email
        }
    }

}
```

**It's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_away" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/legacyGridEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Data class**

class Example private constructor() {

```
companion object {
    //single instance
    val shared: Example by lazy { Example() }
}

fun getData() : List<User> {
    return listOf(
        User("malithdulan7@gmail.com", "malith", "url"),
        User("malithdulan7@gmail.com", "malith", "url"),
        User("malithdulan7@gmail.com", "malith", "url"),
        User("malithdulan7@gmail.com", "malith", "url"),
        User("malithdulan7@gmail.com", "malith", "url")
    )
}
```

}