# Detect the top of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout, onscrolllistener

I have a RecyclerView, first its scrolled down, now when we scroll up, it reach top most point. I want to detect that .Is there any way? I have AppBar whose height is greater than device width. so it cause an fling on scroll. I thought by getting top reached listener manually expand AppBar to avoid fling.

```
    if (layoutManager.firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
    //this is the top of the RecyclerView 
    }
```

this code i already used but my issue is that i can't scroll up RecyclerView after putting this code. Because my RecyclerView uses GridLayoutManager with 3 columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know whether a RecyclerView / LinearLayoutManager is scrolled to top or bottom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841740/how-to-know-whether-a-recyclerview-linearlayoutmanager-is-scrolled-to-top-or-b)

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a `LinearLayoutManager` set on your `RecyclerView` you can use it to find the first visible item:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

if (layoutManager.firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
    //this is the top of the RecyclerView
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: this code i already used but my issue is that i can't scroll up RecyclerView after putting this code. Because my RecyclerView uses GridLayoutManager with 3 columns.

Comment: The correct method name is `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` i guess

Comment: 'findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition' won't work if your items are larger than your screen (can happen easily on small devices)