# Android RecyclerView list has ended

Tags: android

How can i find when android recycler view has reached end of list which is showing?
I want to make a fab visible when the recycler scroll end and it reaches end of content which is showing.

Comment: If you dig a google , 100%  you could find it.

Comment: Use onScrollListener in your Recyclerview. [You can refer to this post for more information.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841740/how-to-know-whether-a-recyclerview-linearlayoutmanager-is-scrolled-to-top-or-b)

Comment: @piyush I googled but not found solution :/ Non of them worked for me so asked

Comment: Have a look at this website: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `size` of your `listItem` if get the list size and compare it in the view holder method:

> `myList.size()==position`

that mean you are the last position of the recycle view item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onBind` method

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
// check if position is last
}
```

and position can tell you if you reached the end.